# Select a different runner for cucumber.api.cli.Main?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, hp-alm

Is it possible to define/specify a runner when starting tests from cucumber's command line(`cucumber.api.cli.Main`)?
My reason for this is so i can generate xml reports in Jenkins and push the results to ALM Octane.

I kind of inherited this project and its using gradle to do a `javaexect` and call `cucumber.api.cli.Main`
I know its possible to do this with `@RunWith(OctaneCucumber.class)` when using JUnit runner + maven (or only JUnit runner), otherwise that tag is ignored. I have the custom runner with that tag but when i run from `cucumber.api.cli.Main` i can't find a way to run with it and my tag just gets ignored.

Comment: cucumber.api.cli.Main does not make use of any runner when called from the command line. You could add the custom code as a plugin, using the -p option. Refer to this article - https://automationrhapsody.com/create-cucumber-jvm-custom-formatter/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Grasshopper suggested didn't exactly work but it made me look in the right direction.

Instead of adding the code as a plugin, i managed to "hack/load" the octane reporter by creating a copy of the `cucumber.api.cli.Main`, using it as a base to run the cli commands and change a bit the `run` method and add the plugin at runtime. Needed to do this because the plugin required quite a few parameters in its constructor. Might not be the perfect solution, but it allowed me to keep the `gradle` build process i initially had.

```
public static byte run(String[] argv, ClassLoader classLoader) throws IOException {
    RuntimeOptions runtimeOptions = new RuntimeOptions(new ArrayList<String>(asList(argv)));

    ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new MultiLoader(classLoader);
    ClassFinder classFinder = new ResourceLoaderClassFinder(resourceLoader, classLoader);
    Runtime runtime = new Runtime(resourceLoader, classFinder, classLoader, runtimeOptions);

    //====================Added the following lines ================
    //Hardcoded runner(?) class. If its changed, it will need to be changed here also
    OutputFile outputFile = new OutputFile(Main.class);
    runtimeOptions.addPlugin(new HPEAlmOctaneGherkinFormatter(resourceLoader, runtimeOptions.getFeaturePaths(), outputFile));
    //==============================================================

    runtime.run();

    return runtime.exitStatus();
}
```